# Guardar valor máxima, mínimo y media de varios campos, guardarlos y borrar el resto cada hora con InfluxDB

Tags: mediaqueries

Estoy haciendo una estación meteorológica. Las lecturas serán guardadas en una base de datos creada con InfluxDB, alojada en una Raspberry pi.

Guardo las mediciones cada minuto. Para reducir el espacio necesario quería dejar la medición máxima, mínima y una media de cada hora y borrar el resto dejando solo esos 3. Pasaría de 60 datos guardados a 3.
Supongo que este proceso lo podré automatizar con un cron para que no dependa de mi, pero esto es otro tema.

Había pensado hacer las peticiones por tiempo así:

```
`select Temp from Datos where time >= '2021-03-13T17:28:31.117793647Z' and time <= '2021-03-13T18:28:31.31284711Z'`
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es:

`invalid timestamp string`

[Documentación InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#basic-group-by-time-syntax)

Por lo que interpreto ese error es porque no es válido el formato fecha?

Soy bastante nuevo tanto con Raspberry como con InfluxDB. Lo que quiero hacer supongo que se puede hacer porque no tengo ni idea si al hacer peticiones de máximo valor se podrán guardar automáticamente el resultado y borrar los 59 restantes.

He probado con otro ejemplo:

```
>  select "Temp" from "Datos" where time >= '2021-03-13T17:28:31.1177936477Z' and time <= '2021-03-13T18:28:31'
```

obteniendo el mismo error.

[Info InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#when-should-i-single-quote-and-when-should-i-double-quote-in-queries)

Estoy bastante perdido. Alguien puede orientarme?

Saludos.